# how to send integers, bools in a bundle via GCM.send

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I see that when bundles are filled with non string data types and sent via GCM, the Smack library receives only string data types.
How to send/receive non string data types via GCM

Comment: I would suggest sending them as String and parsing them locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your payload to JSON and send it as a String. Then you can parse the JSON later on server/client side with desired datatypes.